# Purge all comments feature does not clear the flag indicator

Tags: bug, comments, moderator-tools, flags

I just purged all of the comments from a post in response to a flag. However, the site is still indicating that there are flags present:

[image]

Seems that purging all of the comments is clearing the flag, but it's not clearing the cache on the flag counter. Please fix?

Note: the flag notifier does eventually clear, but after several minutes.

Comment: Caching.  It's always caching.

Comment: @RobertHarvey naturally. I'm just asking for it to get cleared in this instance :)

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/4?m=9650558#9650558, http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/4?m=9766147#9766147, etc. (mod-only)